# XAMPP: PHP file updates not reflecting on site, while JS changes in 'dist' folder work. Help needed. Using VS Code as source code editor

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

I've recently taken over the management of a website after the previous handler left the company in 2022. While I have some familiarity with XAMPP and PHP and am in the process of learning from scratch, I've encountered a problem.

I'm attempting to modify the website's front end by updating certain dates and labels. However, despite trying various approaches like hard refreshing using Ctrl + F5, resetting the server, and so on, I'm unable to make the changes. The PHP file I'm attempting to modify is within the application folder, and interestingly, I can perfectly update the JS file in the dist folder, which reflects on the website.

I'm at a loss here. Unfortunately, I don't have anyone in my circle of colleagues to turn to for assistance, as they are mostly office workers without technical expertise.

My suspicion is that either someone else is managing the frontend(not sure about this), or I might be overlooking certain server-side aspects.

If you have any suggestions regarding my problem, I would greatly appreciate your input. Additionally, if you have further questions about the issue, please don't hesitate to ask. I'll do my best to provide answers.

There aren't any issues within the code, but here's a sample snippet from one of the PHP files. I've altered the text as I'm uncertain about distributing it publicly.

```php-template
<span class="page_name dsplynone" id="page_name">about_page</span>
<div id="parallax-world-of-ugg">
    <section class="parallax-one">
        <div class="container bg-text text-justify text-center">
            <h3>Sample text</h3> <br>
            <p> <strong> Sample text </strong> Sample text <br> <br> Sample text <br> <br> Sample text </p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="block">
        <p><span class="first-character sc">Sample text</span>
            Sample text <strong> Sample text </strong> Sample text </p>
        <hr>
        Sample text <br><br>
        <div class="text-white text-center text-justify" id="bfar_info"> </div> <br>
        <!-- Acknowledgements Modal -->
        <div id="Modal_loader" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3 id="modal_header" class="modal-title"></h3> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="modal_body" class="modal-body"></div>
                    <div class="modal-footer"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="parallax-two">
        <div class="container bg-text text-justify">
            <h3>Sample text</h3> <br>
            <p> <strong> Sample text </strong> <br> Sample text <br><br> <strong> Sample text </strong> <br> Sample text <br><br> Sample text <br><br> Sample text <br><br> Sample text <br><br> Sample text </p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="block">
        <br> <iframe title="methodology pdf" src="dist/docs/METHODOLOGY_comp.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0?v=<?php echo $version; ?>" height="500" width="100%"></iframe>
    </section><br>
</div>
```

The website is hosted on a server, and I access it remotely.

I'm attempting to update some information in http://localhost/about, but despite trying the Ctrl + F5 hard reset method, nothing changes.

I suspect that I might be overlooking something or lacking sufficient knowledge about XAMPP. It could possibly be related to caching, but I'm just guessing. I'm hoping that someone who has encountered a similar issue could assist me.

Here's the directory of the PHP file within the XAMPP server that I'm trying to update: E:\Xampp\htdocs\Project\application\views\pages\users\aboutus.php

Comment: What does this have to do with XAMPP?

Comment: I'm using XAMPP, and the issue probably lies within XAMPP.

Comment: Is this _website_ you're looking at using XAMPP though? What address are you opening in your browser? What PHP file are you editing?

Comment: Yes, I believe it uses XAMPP because it relies on Apache within XAMPP to run. If XAMPP isn't running, the website will be offline. Am I missing something...?

For the address... can u clarify it...?

I'm attempting to edit the text within the homepage, and the file is located in the application folder within the XAMPP directory.

Comment: is that the correct url? the `aboutus.php`. you can try restarting the apache web server from xampp control panel if it refuses to load the new `php` file. but knowing if its the right file will be the best. does the project uses any frameworks or is it pure `php`?

Comment: Oh, that's strange... I believe I'm mistaken; it only displays http://localhost/about on the website, but the code is within aboutus.php... Let me edit it and about restarting apache I already tried that but it doesn't do anything... I've just realized that I'm missing something I hadn't noticed before.

Comment: Sounds like CodeIgniter and the views could be cached. See https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html

Comment: Thanks for your insight, Phil. I'm beginning to realize that I might be missing something crucial. Initially, I thought it was a simple problem, but it seems there's a lot more about the website that I don't know. This uncertainty is why I'm hesitant to take the job—there's no orientation or onboarding process. I feel like I'm a blindfolded donkey. Is there a way to pause this question? I might delete it and ask again once I've learned more about the website

Comment: The question is closed as a duplicate. If the post linked at the top doesn't answer your question, you can [edit] it to provide more details about what you tried and what was the result which will submit it to the re-open queue. If it _does_ solve your question though, then there's nothing else to do

Comment: Alright, thanks.

Comment: Wait! it actually updated! I cleared the cache folder in application folder and after that I did the ctr + f5  and it updated! Super duper mega thanks Phil!!!